# How to create Android UI elements using libgdx

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, libgdx

I am Developing a game for Android using libgdx and I am wondering how to make android UI elements such as EditText and Button. I understand it will work only for Android so I will make something like this:

```
if (Gdx.app.getType() == Application.ApplicationType.Android ) {
...
}
```

I have found that scene2d.ui may be helpful, but I don't use scene2d(actors, stages etc) and not quite familiar with it. Instead I am using Screen's, something like this:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
...
}
```

I`ve seen in game Prototype Defense (written with libgdx) that this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

All the Android-specific code must exist in the Android-back end.  You cannot use Android-specific code in the common project.

All the current libGDX UI elements are custom elements based on OpenGL (so they're somewhat consistent across all the platforms libGDX supports).  There are no elements that wrap Android UI primitives.  For simple things like a button, label or list, I'd suggest using the libGDX UI components for portability.  For more complex elements like text input, or interacting with the platform (e.g., sharing or something) you can use the standard "define an interface" method for invoking platform specific code.

Specifically, say you want to pop up a dialog box for the user to enter their name.  Define

```
public interface PlatformUI {
   public void showHighscoreNameEdit();
}
```

then in your Android project implement this interface in a class using Android primitives.  Then pass an instance of this object into the constructor of your common code.  Now the common code can "call out" to the Android layer.

Something like  this in the Android initialization code:

```
AndroidUI androidUI = new AndroidUI(...);
initialize(new Game(androidUI));
```

And something like this in the platform code:

```
if (timeToShowEditBox) {
  androidUI.showHighscoreNameEdit();
}
```

As @android developer points out, the [AdMobInLibgdx wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx) covers this with the intent of invoking the Android-specific AdMob library, which is very similar in this case.

Answer (score 1):

just use the android UI only in the android project .

they have [**an example**](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx) of how to do it for the admob ads , so that you will be able to put ads on your games.